# Collect awk output in bash script for processing

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a loop in a bash script that processes a number of files in a folder. In my loop, for each file, I execute the below line:

```
awk -F":" '{ print "Name: " $1 "\t\tID:" $3 }' $file
```

I would like to collect the output of all the files processed in some bash variable/array for other processing outside the loop. How can I achieve this in bash?

Comment: Note that processing inside a loop is often unnecessary and performance-wise worse in `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done using shell script array:

```
i=0
for file in file1 file2 ....; do
    output[$i]=$(awk -F":" '{ print "Name: " $1 "\t\tID:" $3 }' "${file}")
    i=$((${i}+1))
done
```

Comment: You should quote that variable in the `awk` command to protect against filenames with a space/special characters in them like so: `"${file}"`

Answer (score 1):

In a similar sense to a0f3dd13 you could use *associative* arrays. They could be useful here especially when it comes time to retrieve the data.

Associative arrays can use a string for their index rather than an integer (they're basically hash maps), so you can more easily retrieve the data.

```
declare -A output
for file in file1 file2 ....;do
    output["$file"]=$(awk -F":" '{ print "Name: " $1 "\t\tID:" $3 }' "${file}")
done
```

Then to retrieve data you can use:

```
echo "${output[file1]}"
```

This would output the results you got from `file1`